# Attach database issue sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm importing a csv to a table in the database in the following way.
In terminal:

```
Terminal>sqlite3 test.db 
sqlite3>.import  /Users/Downloads/test.csv trial1
sqlite3> attach database 'test.db' as 'alias_test';
sqlite3> .database

seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /Users/Downloads/testattach.db                       
2    test_alias       /Users/Downloads/testattach.db
```

But when I restart the terminal and type:

```
>sqlite3 test.db '.database'
```

I get:

```
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /Users/Downloads/testattach.db
```

I want to understand why the attached database name is not shown when I access the database again.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) says:

> The ATTACH DATABASE statement adds another database file to the current database connection.

Restarting creates a new connection.